# Android XML parser for simple xml node strings

Tags: java, android, xml, sax

I need to parse a series of simple XML nodes (String format) as they arrive from a persistent socket connection. Is a custom Android SAX parser really the best way? It seams slightly overkill to do it in [this way](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html)

I had naively hoped I could cast the strings to XML then reference the names / attributes with dot syntax or similar.

Comment: so the format is simple, however is there much data (how long is the series) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use the DOM Parser. It isn't as efficient as SAX, but if it's a simple XML file that's not too large, it's the easiest way to get up and moving.

Great tutorial on how to use it here: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/dom.html

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the XPath library.  This is a more simple way of parsing xml.  It's similar to building SQL queries and regex's.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for a SAX Parser:

- It's much more efficient in terms of memory, especially for larger files: you don't parse an entire document into objects, instead the parser performs a single uni-directional pass over the document and triggers events as it goes through.
- It's actually surprisingly easy to implement: for instance take a look at [Working with XML on Android](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/) by IBM. It's only listings 5 and 6 that are the actual implementation of their SAX parser so it's not a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Konsume-XML](https://gitlab.com/mvysny/konsume-xml): SAX/STAX/Pull APIs are too low-level and hard to use; DOM requires the XML to fit into memory and is still clunky to use. Konsume-XML is based on Pull and therefore it's extremely efficient, yet the API is higher-level and much easier to use.