# How to Read same name child tag from xml in android

Tags: android, xml

hello i am new in android
i want know how to iterate child node  from xml
xml is as follow

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <ACT>                
    <Item>ABC</Item>
    <Item>XYZ</Item> </ACT>
```

i want to take Item VAlue From ACT tag

Comment: Just curious: did you do a search on the internet before posting this question? A simple search on "android parse xml" will give you loads of pointers.

Comment: yes i search on internet but i didnt find same child node name example

Comment: @PeterLillevold i found many example of different name child tag but not to same name child tag name example

Comment: doesn't matter if the child nodes have the same name or not, using a DOM parser or a SAX parser you can easily inspect the nodes (by element name) and pull out the value when you find the expected node.

Comment: ...and so you are aware: people here on SO will not usually "give you the codez". You will have to take the information and guidance provided here, put your mind to it and do the effort yourself.

Comment: @PeterLillevold i post my code which i try

Comment: it out put only ABC not come XYz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5412274/35245).

**Update:** the code posted will only list the first Item because the loop over `nodes3` in `onCreate` loops only over the `ACT` elements. Since you have only one of these, the loop will iterate once, write out the first child and then terminate. You must have a second loop inside your loop where you iterate over all child nodes of element `e`.

Comment: can you give me how to iterare that second loop in my code..see my code is i post above

Comment: @user1153176 - you have already done such a loop with the `nodes3` object. You should do the same inside that loop, but then with the `e` object. I will not code that for you.

Comment: @user1153176 - glad to be of some assistance. That said, my votes goes to questions I find helpful, interesting or well written. Sorry to say that your question does not reach the bar. A friendly tip for your future questions: try to improve your spelling, put some effort into formatting, and clearly show that you are putting some effort into solving the problem yourself. Do NOT ask that people write the solution for you, this only shows that you are willing to waste others precious time on your problem. Such manners are generally not well received :)

Answer (score 0):

SAX parser is a great way to parse this kind of an xml file. Follow some SAXParsing tutorial.

Comment: http://as400samplecode.blogspot.in/2011/11/android-parse-xml-file-example-using.html u can check this tutorial, this is simple and easy.