# Android XML Parsing Issue - Multiple occurances of same tag

Tags: android, android-listview, android-xml

I followed a tutorial located here: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/ and so far everything worked fine with it. However this only worked nice when there were specific XML tags to go through, such as:

```
<tag1>
<gettag></gettag>
<gettag2></gettag2>
</tag1>
```

However my main issue is that I need to get multiple items from within a single tag, like this:

```
<tag1>
<tag2>text</tag2>
<tag2>text again</tag2>
<tag2>more text</tag2>
</tag1>
```

I am not able to use the tutorial code to get all of the tag2 items (it stops at the first one). Does anyone know of a good way to grab those "tag2" tags above and spit out the results into a listview?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something you may need to do is,

keep a list, If endElement() is tag2, add readtext to list. if endElement is tag1, then create new List and elements.

Check this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239506/how-to-read-same-name-child-tag-from-xml-in-android).

Comment: Perfect. The start and end elements seem to work perfectly. That discussion did not provide an immediate answer but gave me enough information to figure it out.